# replace a word with string in a file using shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I have a file in which I have to convert the string "lock allpages" into STRING
" LOCATION 'hdfs://LOCATION/DIRECTORY/TBL;' " . I tried sed but it's throwing some error. can someone suggest the changes that I need to do. I tried below but it's not working. and also can someone suggest how to use sed for replacing multiple strings at once

```
sed -i 's/lock allpages/LOCATION 'hdfs://LOCATION/DIRECTORY/TBL';'
```

Comment: "it's throwing some error" -- what error exactly? "it's not working" -- what _is_ it doing and how does that differ from what you expect? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your single quotes and forward slashes in your `sed` statement. ..  That and you're not COMPLETING the `sed` statement ..  You need to close your second argument with a slash -> `/` (Or whatever delimiter you choose)

```
sed -i 's/lock allpages/LOCATION \'hdfs:\/\/LOCATION\/DIRECTORY\/TBL;\'/g'
```

OR if you put the statement in double quotes . There's no need to escape the single quotes

```
sed -i "s/lock allpages/LOCATION 'hdfs:\/\/LOCATION\/DIRECTORY\/TBL;'/g"
```

FURTHER --  If you used a different delimiter .. Like a pipe `|` --  There would be no need for escaping at all...

```
sed -i "s|lock allpages|LOCATION 'hdfs://LOCATION/DIRECTORY/TBL;'|g"
```

Comment: You cannot escape a single quote inside a single quoted string.